# Possibly outdated info from Digital Ocean on getting Phalcon up and running?

Tags: .htaccess, phalcon, digital-ocean

I am getting to know Phalcon on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu instance. I am following their [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-phalcon-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) and have an issue with the instruction to edit the default virtual host file. They recommend editing `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` but that file doesn't exist; instead, I have edited `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as follows:

`<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>`

I have **mod_rewrite** enabled and I have restarted the server, and I have also written the htaccess files as referenced in the DO tutorial referenced above. All told, having tried to follow both the Phalcon and DO tutorials in an effort to get my "Hello World" to display, my app structure is:

```
.
./html
./html/index.html
./html/info.php
./my_app
./my_app/public
./my_app/public/js
./my_app/public/index.php
./my_app/public/.htaccess
./my_app/public/css
./my_app/public/img
./my_app/.htaccess
./my_app/app
./my_app/app/models
./my_app/app/views
./my_app/app/views/index
./my_app/app/views/index/index.phtml
./my_app/app/controllers
./my_app/app/controllers/IndexController.php
```

Yet when I try to access my project folder from the browser or anything rather than my XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/index.html page that displays the Apache welcome page, I get 403 errors.

I suspect the DO tutorial may be out of date slightly based on its description of the file structure. Clearly I'm missing something obvious at this beginning stage. How do I configure my htaccess file(s) to allow access to my files? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are the permissions to the folders/files? (in digit form)

Comment: @Jon: The my_app and html folders are 755; all else appear to be 644.

Comment: As the title notes, the article targets Ubuntu 12.04 On more recent releases, the equivalent file is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` Apache's DocumentRoot has also changed from `/var/www/` to `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andrewsomething had it right -- thanks very much. I had to revert my changes to `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and edit the correct .conf file, as well as move my app into the html directory. It pays to pay attention...